# Insert 10,000,000+ rows in grails

Tags: grails, bigdata

I've read a lot of articles recently about populating a grails table from huge data, but seem to have hit a ceiling. My code is as follows:

```
class LoadingService {
    def sessionFactory
    def dataSource
    def propertyInstanceMap = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DomainClassGrailsPlugin.PROPERTY_INSTANCE_MAP

    def insertFile(fileName) {
        InputStream inputFile = getClass().classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName)
        def pCounter = 1
        def mCounter = 1
        Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        inputFile.splitEachLine(/\n|\r|,/) { line -> 
            line.each { value ->
                if(value.equalsIgnoreCase('0') { 
                    pCounter++
                    return
                }
                sql.executeInsert("insert into Patient_MRNA (patient_id, mrna_id, value) values (${pCounter}, ${mCounter}, ${value.toFloat()})")
                pCounter++
            }
            if(mCounter % 100 == 0) {
                cleanUpGorm()
            }
            pCounter = 1
            mCounter++
        }
    }

    def cleanUpGorm() {
        session.currentSession.clear()
        propertyInstanceMap.get().clear()
    }
}
```

I have disabled secondary cache, I'm using assigned ids, and I am explicitly handling this many to many relationship through a domain, not the hasMany and belongsTo.

My speed has increased monumentally after applying these methods, but after a while the inserts slow down to the point of almost stopping compared to about 623,000 per minute at the beginning.

Is there some other memory leak that I should be aware of or have I just hit the ceiling in terms of batch inserts in grails?

To be clear it takes about 2 minutes to insert 1.2 million rows, but then they start to slow down.

Comment: what database do you use? btw, you're executing plain sql `insert into`, don't understand how domain config, caching, etc can relate to this

Comment: it's an h2 database. Ok gotcha, I was just trying out different methods and see if I got results. Sql was kind of my last ditch effort so there may be some things that are left over from when I was using gorm.

Comment: h2 can read directly from file, see http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html?highlight=CSVREAD#csvread

Comment: thanks, yeah that's what I was using for my other tables. This last one is a joint table, so I feel a little more comfortable with groovy, but will probably revert to this if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing batch inserts, it's much more efficient

```
def updateCounts = sql.withBatch { stmt ->
     stmt.addBatch("insert into TABLENAME ...")
     stmt.addBatch("insert into TABLENAME ...")
     stmt.addBatch("insert into TABLENAME ...")
     ...
 }
```

Comment: Got it, will give it a try as soon as possible. Is there a max to how many one could do at a time?

Comment: I think the only limit is your heap size. With every new batch you increase your used heap size.

Comment: thank you soo much! I ended up doing this but also splitting the file in chunks

Answer (score 1):

I have fought with this in earlier versions of Grails. Back then I resorted to either simply run the batch manually in proper chunks or use another tool for the batch import, such as Pentaho Data Integration (or other ETL tool or DIY).

Comment: I ended up doing the batch manually with the stmt.addBatch in the answer by Davor, only because this is a one time thing. Otherwise I would've used some other tool. Thanks!