# Grails Excel import fails for huge data

Tags: excel, grails, apache-poi, grails-plugin

I am using grails 2.3.7 and the latest excel-import plugin (1.0.0). My requirement is that I need to copy the contents of an excel sheet completely as it is into the database. My database is mssql server 2012.

I have got the code working for the development version. The code works fine when the number of records are few or may be upto a few hundreds.

But while in production the excel sheet will be having as many as 50,000 rows and over 75 columns.

Initially I faced a data out of memory exception. I increased the heap size to as much as 8GB, but now the thread keeps running on and on without termination. No errors are generated.

Please note that this is a once in while operation and it will be carried out by a person who will ensure that this operation does not hamper other operations running parellely. So need to worry about the huge load of this operation. I can afford to run it.

When the records are upto 10,000 with the same number of columns the data gets copied in around 5 mins. If now I have 50,000 rows then the time taken should ideally be around 5 times more, which is around 25 mins. But the code kept running for more than an hour without termination.

Any idea how to go about this issue. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you load 5 times more data in memory, it doesn't always take 5 times more. I guess that most of 8GB are in virtual memory and the virtual memory is very slow on hardware. Try to decrease the memory, run some memory tests and try to use as much as possible the RAM.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, a normal problem with large batch operations in Grails. I think you have memory leaks that radically slow down the operation as it proceeds.

My solution has been to use an ETL tool such as Pentaho Kettle for the import, or chunk the import into manageable pieces. See this related question:

[Insert 10,000,000+ rows in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26417969/insert-10-000-000-rows-in-grails)

Comment: The problem is that I donot have the option of using an ETL. I need to do it in grails alone.

Comment: Then try Oliver's approach, working with CSV could prove to be much faster. If it still slows down as it proceeds, chunk the import into smaller pieces - you could probably do that in code rather than splitting the file if that is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Not technically an answer to your problem, but have you considered just using CSV instead of of excel?

From a users point of view, saving as a CSV before importing is not a lot of work.

I am loading, validating and saving CSVs with 200-300 000 rows without a hitch.
Just make sure you have the logic in a service so it puts a transaction around it.

A bit more code to decode csv maybe, especially to translate to various primitives, but it should be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Oliver. I will definitely try it out.